# radomly selecting n elements from an array on every loop with c++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, permutation

I am trying to write a c++ code that get inputs form user and stores in an array and then prints back the elements randomly in groups of 4.

below is my code.

```
 #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
      int i; int arr[5];
        cout << "Enter some numbers" << endl;
         for(i=0; i<5; i++){
            cin >> arr[i];
         }


        for(int k=0; k<5; k++){
                cout << arr[k];
                cout << " ";
        }
        cout << " " << endl; 
}
```

Comment: 1. What's your question? 2. You have *undefined behavior* in both `for` loops (you are accessing the array out of bounds)

Comment: Why did you tag your question with C?

Comment: @pmg it's c++ not c.

Comment: suppose that you change the for loop to k<5...?

Comment: @NtirpangLouis if you already know that it is C++, not C then please do not tag it as C from now on!!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala it was probably a typing mistake.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to get four random numbers from a pool of 4 or more numbers, then an easy way to do that is to just shuffle all the entries each time and return the first 4.

Comment: how can i implement the shuffle?

Comment: @NtirpangLouis: Search for "Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm". Should bring up lots of links, e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Comment: @NtirpangLouis if not forbidden by the assignment, [use `std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle)